# How do I sort a Django queryset by frequency of occurance from a list and ensure the remaining objects follow?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django application running Django 3+ and Python 3.8+.

I am trying to fill the front page of my site with relevant accounts to the user currently logged in. So if user john_person is logged in, I want them to see users who have similar resources to them followed by accounts who just have a lot of resources followed by the remaining accounts.

**models.py**

```
class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Anonymous')
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='User')
  user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Resource(models.Model):
  user_account=models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='resources')
  resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Tag(models.Model):
  resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tags')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have a list of common tags (belonging to the logged in user), let's call this:

```
common_tags=['tag1','tag2','tag3']
```

This list can vary in length.

My model parent-children are related by a many to one relationship.

User->Resource->Tag

Users have resources, and resources have tags.

**My goal:**

I need to be able to query all my users and filter it in such a way that I get an ordered queryset where the users who have the most `common_tags` as their tags come up on top. That set of people need to be sorted by who has more tags in common (not based on how many of each tag they have, just the common occurrences with logged in user). This same query set should also contain the remaining users who do not have any of the common tags. Lastly, this queryset should not have any repeats.

So far I have:

```
  relevant_accounts= User.objects.all()\
  .annotate(count_resources=Count('resources')).order_by('-count_resources')\
  .order_by(Case(When(resources__tags__name__in=common_tags, then=0),default=1, 
  output_field=FloatField()))
```

**This appears to work, but I get repeated values.**

Running .distinct() does not resolve the issue.

**Edit: Sample Input/Output**

User A: `Tags = ['A','A','B','C']`
User B: `Tags = ['A','B','B','C']`
User C: `Tags = ['A','B','B','B']`

Sample User 1: `common_tags=['A','C']`

Return: Users A->B->C

Sample User 2: `common_tags=['B','C']`

Return: Users B->C->A OR C->B->A

**Edit : Also tried this. I like the level of customization I get but still duplicates.**

```
is_in_query = Q(resources__tags__name__icontains=common_tags)
    is_not_in_query = ~Q(resources__tags__name__in=common_tags)

    qs_simple = (User.objects.filter(is_private=False).annotate(count_resources=Count('resources'))
    .annotate(
    search_type_ordering=Case(
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=6) & is_in_query, then=1),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=3) & Q(count_resources__lte=5) & is_in_query, then=2),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=0) & Q(count_resources__lte=2) & is_in_query, then=3),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=3) & is_not_in_query, then=4),
    When(Q(count_resources__gte=0) & Q(count_resources__lte=2) & is_not_in_query, then=5),
    default=7,
    output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
    .order_by('-search_type_ordering',).distinct()
    )
```

Comment: it is highly recommended to add relevant models

Comment: Added more details and models.py

Comment: I may have a solution, but it is PostgreSQL only, because it involves using `distinct` on specific fields (which translates in `DISTINCT ON` statements that are Postgres-only). Is it OK for you?

Comment: My database doesn't support putting fields in distinct is that's what you mean. Like distinct('user') etc won't work. Feel free to post it though I will definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using a `Count` annotation with a filter. First annotate each `User` with the number of resources and common tags and then order by the annotations

```
User.objects.annotate(
    count_resources=Count('resources', distinct=True), 
    count_common_tags=Count(
        'resources__tags__name',
        filter=Q(resources__tags__name__in=common_tags)
    )
).order_by(
    '-count_common_tags',
    '-count_resources'
)
```

Comment: This answer is very close. I still get the wrong order though. What I mean is: I get the relevant users come up first, but then it is followed sporadically by users that have no resources. My ideal solution is one where I get relevant users first, then users with most resources, then the rest.

Comment: @LearnIT Adding `distinct=True` to the `count_resources` annotation should get more accurate results (updated sorry I missed that) but that does not explain the users with no resources... Are you using the above queryset as-is or are you applying more filters to it?

Comment: I was trying it as is. I updated the code with the distinct argument and refreshed a few times and the missing figures appear to be gone. Maybe it was something on my end. This seems to work pretty well. I will try it on a real data set soon, thank you!

Comment: By the way, just to clarify --->   count_common_tags=Count(
        'resources__tags__name',
        filter=Q(resources__tags__name__in=common_tags)
    ) ---> Is this allowing us to count the number of common resources within the annotation?

Comment: @LearnIT Yes, it counts all common tags and adds the result to the annotated field. Using Count with a filter works well in this case since it doesn't filter out results that have no common tags